# how to start Process.start from a web service hosted via a windows service

Tags: web-services, rest, process.start

I am trying to call **Proccess.Start("")** from a WCF REST service hosted in a Windows Service through its **OnStart** method. And i am returning a **bool as Process.Start()**, though it is returning true, the process is not started.

Please provide me a way to solve this issue. and how can i start a process from a web service hosted through a windows service